# Request to a Threadpool from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I need to make an application that generates a list containing the following characters: H,A,O,*,#,@. The last two are control characters. The "#" makes the list divide in two (like a tree) and each sublist have to continue filling until the "@" appears, which indicates the list is finish. This process continues until all of the sublists have the "@" or the lenght of all the sublists together are 10000.

Then I have to iterate through the list using threads, and for each of the characters paint a different image in a frame. When I find a "#", the thread have to start two other threads to iterate throught the next two sublists and it have to terminate.

I am getting stuck in the part when I have to start the new threads and finish the first one. Googling I found a way to do this, but I feel that is a bad way to do it. So my question is:
Is there another way to make this?

```
public class PainterThread implements Runnable {


public PainterThread(Iterator pIterator, ExecutorService pPool, PaintingPanel pPanel) {
    _iteratorList = pIterator;  //the Iterator of the list
    _Pool = pPool;          //I pass the ThreadPool as a parameter in order to make the request to create new threads
    _PanelToPaint = pPanel;// The Panel which going to paint the images
}

//Methods
@Override
public void run() {
    while (_iteratorList.hasNext()) {
        Node actualNode = (Node) _iteratorList.next();
        switch (actualNode.getControlSign()) {
            case "H":
                _PanelToPaint.addShapes(new Square(actualNode.getPositionX(), actualNode.getPositionY(), actualNode.getSize()));
                _PanelToPaint.repaint();
                break;
            case "A":
                _PanelToPaint.addShapes(new Triangle(actualNode.getPositionX(), actualNode.getPositionY(), actualNode.getSize()));
                _PanelToPaint.repaint();
                break;
            case "O":
                _PanelToPaint.addShapes(new Circle(actualNode.getPositionX(), actualNode.getPositionY(), actualNode.getSize()));
                _PanelToPaint.repaint();
                break;
            case "*":
                _PanelToPaint.addShapes(new Asterisk(actualNode.getPositionX(), actualNode.getPositionY(), actualNode.getSize()));
                _PanelToPaint.repaint();
                break;
            case "#":
                LinkedList actualList = (LinkedList) _iteratorList.next();
                _Pool.submit(new PainterThread(actualList.iterator(), _Pool,_PanelToPaint)); //Here is my question. Is there another way to make this?
                if (_iteratorList.hasNext()) {
                    actualList = (LinkedList) _iteratorList.next();
                    _Pool.submit(new PainterThread(actualList.iterator(), _Pool, _PanelToPaint));
                }
                break;
            case "@":
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void setIterator(Iterator pNewIterator) {
    _iteratorList = pNewIterator;
}
//Atributes
private Iterator _iteratorList;
private ExecutorService _Pool;
private PaintingPanel _PanelToPaint;
```

}

Comment: Why cannot you make all the stuff in one thread?

Comment: A thread will terminate when it reaches the end of it's `run` method. So when you encounter a '@' character, spawn your two threads off, then just break out of the run method.

Comment: "Is there another way to make this?" Could you please be more specific, because it's not so easy to have a look deep inside your code and understand what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. First I can't do this using only one Thread because is an assignment of the University. I want to known if there could be a way to send a message to the pool and then the ThreadPool could know what exactly do or something like that. I really don't like  the fact to send the threadpool into the Thread in order to start the other threads

Comment: but that's what you normally have to do when you use ThreadPools: split your work into pieces (in your case, jobs that process list segments) and submit these to the ThreadPool. In those jobs, you can create new jobs and submit those, too. Using ThreadPools is not so much about thinking in threads, but jobs.